# View controller dismiss very fast after saving to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

everytime I try to save something to firebase my controller crash, the app don't crash and the information do save, but the view controller get dismissed really fast when I try to save even if I don't dismiss the vc. Thanks for your help!

Here's my viewController:

**Example 1:**

```
import UIKit

import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class EditAccountVC: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var profileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var websiteField: UITextField!

    var user: Users!
    var imageChanged: Bool = false


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).observe(.value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            if let postDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                let key = snapshot.key
                self.user = Users(key: key, artistData: postDict)
            }
            if let user = self.user {
                self.nameField.text = user.name
                self.emailField.text = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.email
                self.websiteField.text = user.website
                self.profileImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(self.user.profilePicUrl)") , placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"User-70") , options: .continueInBackground)
            }
        }
        //profileImage.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "image", options: .new, context: nil)
    }

    //    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    //        print("IMAGE CHANGES")
    //    }

    @IBAction func doneBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
        let spinner: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: activityIndicator)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = spinner
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        let name = self.nameField.text!
        let email = self.emailField.text!
        let website = self.websiteField.text!


        FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.updateEmail(email, completion: { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage.image!, 1)
        let imagePath = "profileImage\(user.userId)userPic.jpeg"
        let imageRef = STORAGE.child(imagePath)
        let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        imageRef.put(imageData!, metadata: metaData) { (metaData, error) in
            let changeRequest = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.profileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest?.displayName = name

            if let photoUrl = metaData!.downloadURL() {
                changeRequest?.photoURL = photoUrl
            }

            changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
                if error == nil {
                    let user = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!
                    let userInfo = ["email": email, "name": name, "website": website, "uid": user.uid, "profileImg": String(describing: user.photoURL!)] as [String : Any]
                    let userRef = DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(user.uid)
                    userRef.updateChildValues(userInfo, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reference) in

                    })
                }

            })
        }
    }


    @IBAction func editImageBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = Alerts()
        alert.changeProfilePicture(self)

    }


    @IBAction func cancelBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }


    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
        profileImage.image = image
        self.imageChanged = true
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What viewController is being dismissed? I don't see anything in the code you added that's dismissing a ViewController.

Comment: And that's my problem, the view controller dismiss even if I don't dismiss it. Everytime I save to Firebase.

Comment: Do you have some sort of delegate protocol with the Firebase classes? Is it possible there is a callback happening?

Comment: No I don't. But do you see anything wrong with the way I save or remove value?

Comment: It looks like in your `remove` method you're showing an alert, but you haven't sent it back to the main thread. You shouldn't ever do any UI updates on a background thread. It will cause all kinds of issues.

Comment: The viewcontroller still "crash" if I remove the Alert.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There's no error, the app is not crashing but the viewcontroller dismiss

Comment: How is this ViewController even being presented? What is the presenting VC? Like I said, I don't see anything with the code you've shown that would cause the behavior you are describing. I believe the issue is localized elsewhere.

Comment: The view controller is being presented by a Segue. I just updated my question, to show you the full code.

Comment: So let me make sure I understand completely. You present this VC with a segue, then this Firebase request executes, and when it completes, this `EditAccountVC` then disappears, and you go back to the VC that originally performed the segue?

Comment: No, when I press the "doneBtnTapped()" to save the new details to firebase the viewcontroller dismiss.

Comment: I don't know what's causing it. I would recommend doing some simple debugging. Insert a breakpoint at the beginning of `doneBtnTapped(_:)` and then after you tap on it, step through line by line to determine which line of code is causing the dismissal

Comment: Could it be that the done button, is a standard "done" uibarbuttonitem, which automatically dismisses the modal? In the same way that the standard "Ok" button on an alertView, dismisses the alert?

Comment: No @JordiBruin the done button is a custom uibarbuttonitem

Comment: You should add more info. Is the VC modally presented or pushed? Your code has a `popViewController` statement but you're trying to use `self.dismiss` so I can't really tell if it's modal or pushed. What do you mean by "everytime I try to save something"? is that when `doneBtnTapped` is triggered?

Comment: Hi @ThunderStruct, what info do you want? Yes, everytime I tapped done, to save the new data to firebase. It saved but after the view controller dismiss. The `popViewController` statement is to cancel. I'm not trying to use  `self.dismiss`. If you need more info, just ask. Thanks

Comment: Ok so it uploads the image properly and updates the values in the database and then the ViewController gets popped, right? If so, please add the custom UIBarButtonItem code you wrote because there's nothing wrong with the code you posted

Comment: Exactly!! The UIBarButtonItem  is set in the storyboard. I just added a screenshot in my question.